# A question about continuity of a specific function with probability measure

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Let $X$ be a compact metric space, and $\Theta$ be a **finite** space, endowed with their own $\sigma$-algebra.

Let $f \colon X \times \Theta \to \mathbb{R}$ be a *Caratheodory* function such that
(1) for each $x \in X$, the function $f(x, \cdot) \colon \Theta \to \mathbb{R}$
is measurable; and (2) for each $\theta \in \Theta$, the function $f( \cdot, \theta) \colon X \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

Given each $x \in X$, we have a probability distribution $\pi( \cdot \,| \, x) \colon 2^{\Theta} \to [0,1]$. In particular, given any fixed $x \in X$,
it will generate a corresponding probability distribution $\pi$ on $2^\Theta$.

I am curious that

> Under what kind of conditions (assumptions) imposed on this probability distribution $\pi$ , the map $$X \ni x \mapsto \int_\Theta f(x,\theta) \, \pi( \mathrm{d} \theta \,| \,x) \in \mathbb{R}$$
>   will be **continuous** on $X$?

Any idea or suggestions are most welcome!

Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks @Michael, you’re right. Actually, the space $\Theta$ I considered was a compact metric space, but now I just want to simplify the question and restrict it to be finite.

Comment: Thanks @Michael . I totally agree with you. In fact, I really need the probability distribution $\pi(\cdot | x)$ depending on $x$. This means for each $x \in X$, I have a different probability distribution defined on $2^\Theta$. Also, the space $\Theta$ is at least not trivial. In such a setting, what can I do to ensure the map $h(x)$ is continuous on $X$? Is it possible to do that? Thanks a million again :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your integral is 
$$ h(x) = \sum_{\theta\in \Theta} f(x,\theta) \pi(\{\theta\}|x) \quad \forall x \in X $$
if $\pi(\{\theta\}|x) = \pi(\{\theta\})$ for all $x \in X$ then this is a sum of a finite number of functions that are continuous in $x$, and hence is continuous in $x$. More generally, if $\pi(\{\theta\}|x)$ is continuous in $x$ for each $\theta \in \Theta$, then this is a sum of a finite numer of functions that are continuous in $x$ (and hence is continuous in $x$).

Else, it is easy to get a discontinuous example (despite my incorrect comment from before that tried to do it with $\Theta$ being only a 1-element set) by defining $\pi(\{\theta\}|x)$ discontinuously.  Define $X=[0,1]$, define $\Theta=\{0,1\}$, $f(x,0)=0$, $f(x,1) = 1$ for all $x \in [0,1]$, and define: 
$$ (\pi(\{0\}|x), \pi(\{1\}|x)) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
(1,0) &\mbox{ if $x \in [0,1/2)$} \\
(1/2,1/2)  & \mbox{ if $x \in [1/2,1]$} 
\end{array}
\right.$$
Then 
$$h(x)= \pi(\{1\}|x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
0 &\mbox{ if $x \in [0,1/2)$} \\
1/2  & \mbox{ if $x \in [1/2,1]$} 
\end{array}
\right.$$ 
and this is discontinuous in $x$.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer @Michael. I should clarify initially that given any fixed $x \in X$, we have a different probability distribution; that can be reviewed as for each state variable $x$ in a State space $X$, I will have a different probability distribution on $\Theta$ and such a probability distribution depends on different observations of $x$. In this setting, could we still get some result for continuity of the map $h$? Would you mind rethinking about the question based on this setting please? I sincerely appreciate your kind help!

Comment: I think this is what my example already does.  Note that in this example I refined my answer to have $\Theta$ now a 2-element set rather than a 1-element set (for a 1-element set then the mass function must be 1 (in order to be a mass function) so I could not really define $\pi(\{\theta\}|x)$  discontinuously in $x$ when $\Theta$ is a 1-element set).

Comment: Thanks @Michael . Did you mean that a sufficient condition for the continuity of the function $h$ is $\pi(\{\theta\} | x)$ is continuous in $x$ for each $\theta \in \Theta$? Besides, may I ask what do you think if we extend the finite space of $\Theta$ to a compact metric space? Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Yes, my first paragraph says it is sufficient to have $\pi(\{\theta\}|x)$ continuous in $x$ for each $\theta \in \Theta$, for the case when $\Theta$ is a finite set.

Comment: Thank you very much @Michael . I understand now. But still curious about what if the space $\Theta$ is allowed to be compact. In this setting, since the space $\Theta$ could be infinite or countably infinite,  such a sufficient condition may fail. Do you think is there any reasonable assumption imposed on $\pi$ that would guarantee the continuity of $h$ with integral? Many thanks :-)

Comment: With some Lipschitz assumptions it should work, such as for a uniform Lipschitz constant. You can start by considering integrals $\int f(x,\theta)p(x,\theta)d\theta$ where $p(x,\theta)$ is a continuous PDF over $\theta$ for each $x$ and $f, p$ have suitable Lipschitz properties. (PDFs are easier to think about then general integrals.)

Comment: Thanks for your kind guidance @Michael . I will search a bit for which kind of PDF possess Lipschitz properties, since I am new in probability theory. Again thank you so much for your big help!

Comment: Dear @Michael , how are you? I realized from the tag that you are also interested in optimization. Therefore, would you mind me asking you a few questions about optimization and the dual theory please? The first question is linked to this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3013592/a-question-about-the-equality-of-the-solutions-to-primal-and-dual-problems . It would be great if you could take a look at it and give me some advice please. Thank you so much in advance! :-)

Comment: @Paradiesvogel : I gave a comment on your linked question.

Comment: Dear @Michael , I got your comment and will keep thinking about it later. Thank you so much for your kindness!